# How to stop a running app in iPad 6 and iPhone6 simulator?

Tags: xcode

How to stop a app/project running on simulator iPhone6 iPad6 ,in absence of button?

Comment: If you are running the app thru Xcode, you can click the `Stop` button in Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press `Shift` + `Command` + `H` to close the app.

And to view the background apps, holding the `Shift` + `Command` buttons, double press the `H`.